# How to reshape pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['name','number','dob'],'b':['myamulla','1234','1999-01-01']})
```

[image]

I would like to have this reshaped as below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and transposition ([`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html)):

```
out = df.set_index('a').T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([df['b'].tolist()], columns=df['a'].tolist())
```

Output:

```
       name number         dob
0  myamulla   1234  1999-01-01
```

Answer (score 2):

Use DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([df['b'].tolist()], columns=df['a'].tolist())
print (df)
       name number         dob
0  myamulla   1234  1999-01-01
```

Or select numpy array from DataFrame:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
df = pd.DataFrame([a[:, 1]], columns=a[:, 0])
print (df)
       name number         dob
0  myamulla   1234  1999-01-01
```

Or convert to dictionaries:

```
d = df.to_dict('list')
df = pd.DataFrame([d['b']], columns=d['a'])
print (df)
       name number         dob
0  myamulla   1234  1999-01-01
```

Comment: this wasn't your [original answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEIfZ.png)…

Comment: @mozway - Yop, i change it.